# .NET 7 Blazor-WASM publish doesn't work - TypeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Import #0 module="a" error: module is not an object or function

Tags: blazor, .net-7.0

I've converted my Blazor project from .NET6 to .NET7.  It is a Blazor WASM project.  It runs great on my dev machine.  The version compiled in the build system doesn't work in production.  The web browser just gets stuck at "Loading...".  There error in the console says

TypeError: WebAssembly.instantiate(): Import #0 module="a" error: module is not an object or function
u @ blazor.webassembly.js:1

Any ideas?  I've cleared my caches, deleted all the build server obj/bin folders, verified the build tools and code building built are the same version.  I feel like I'm missing a file or something.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I encountered the same problem, i deleted the bin and the obj folders in BOTH the server project and the client project. after building and publishing, the error was gone and everything was fine.